# How to Deserialize a list of json data from a api?

Tags: android, json, xamarin

this is the code i am using to Deserialize the data but it says it cannot Deserialize the current json object

```
var root = JObject.Parse (responseFromServer);
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer ();
            var expectedObject = serializer.Deserialize<ProfileModel> (root ["data"].CreateReader ());
```

Profiles Model has :

```
public List<int> profiles { get; set; }
```

And this the is the json data form api

```
{

"data": {
    "id": 4,
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "profiles": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 31,
                "name": "Apple"
            },
            {
                "id": 32,
                "name": "Pear"
            }
        ]
    }
}

}
```

Comment: use this generator: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have something like this (it looks like there is only one profile in there, not a collection):

```
public class Datum
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class DataResponse
{
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

With Json.NET the deserialization would be:

```
   var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataResponse>(responseFromServer);
```

Comment: Note that the json is all in a lower case, and your example will not be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

"profiles" contains an object called "data" which contains an array of Profiles. Also, you'll need a Profile object which contains an "id" and a "name".